# Use generics with legacy code

Tags: java, generics

In my project, the external API we used is not genericfied, so there's a class called `ItemList` which is an implementation of `java.util.List`, it holds a list of `Item` objects. however in our new code we express this as `List<Item>`, I want to write a method that can takes both `ItemList` and `List<Item>`, 
I tried this kind of signature:

```
public static void readList(List<?> list) {}
```

it works fine, but the problem is there is a cast from `Object` to `Item` inside this method, which is used when the argument is `ItemList`, and not necessary for `List<Item>`, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Funny how you think Java's implementation of "generics" does anything to "modernize" your code, considering that they just get thrown out at the earliest convenience by the compiler... Ahh to be young and innocent again!

Comment: @Blindy, sadly SO can't vote down for your junk comments.

Comment: @Blindy:  Just try to write modern code to deal with a "legacy" API that doesn't do generics... then tear your eyes out at the sheer amount of crap you have to deal with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `ItemList` is an implementation of `List`, and if you know it contains `Item` instances, just cast it to `List<Item>`. You'll get a type safety warning, but it's not less safe than casting each element of the `ItemList` to `Item`.

Comment: Yes, but this may require users who use your API to do a casting to eliminate a warning.

Comment: When using raw types, you need casts. Generics were introduced to be able to avoid them. Since your legacy API still uses raw types, you still need casts. You may cast the whole list to a generic list, or cast every element to Item, it's up to you. But you won't be able to avoid casts.

Answer (score 2):

Can you write your new API to handle `List<Item>` so it is clean moving forward, and then provide a static conversion method to act as an adapter for the legacy uses `List<Item> asList(ItemList itemList)`?  This way you isolate where the ugly unchecked conversion happens.

Answer (score 1):

What about providing two methods - one for each parameter type.  At least you only have only one type safety warning in a known place that has been discussed and accepted:

```
public static void readList(List<Item> list) {
    // do something
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static void readItemList(List<?> list) {
    readList((List<Item>)list); // Type safety warning tucked away in here 
}
```

Although you don't have type safety, the name of the method `readItemList` is at least a strong hint to coders of the list type they are expected to be passing in.

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading the API correctly, java.lang.Class:getTypeParameters() looks promising.
Try:

```
if(list.getClass().getTypeParameters().length == 0) {
    // Code for non-generic
} else {
    // Genericized
}
```